# Set switch statement based on number of clicks

Tags: java, android

My application is crashing and I believe it is due to the `SharedPreferencesManager prefManager = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance(this);` being stored globally in `Content`class. However, if I take it out of there then I cannot use `prefManager` within the switch statement further down.

I want to use the number of clicks from `prefManager` to determine my switch statement. How can I get around this?

```
public class Content extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button selectAnotherButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_content);

        final SharedPreferencesManager prefManager = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance(this);

        selectAnotherButton = findViewById(R.id.button_select_another);

        selectAnotherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                prefManager.increaseClickCount();

                for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i+=2) {
                    ShowRewardDialog();
                }
            }
        });

    private void ShowRewardDialog() {

        String message = "";
        //show dialog
        // set text based on an if statement you need to create

        switch (SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance(this).increaseClickCount()){

            case 2 :
                message = "You are rewarded with a video";
                break;
            case 4 :
                message = "You are rewarded with a the yellow smiley face in the homepage";
                break;
            case 6 :
                message = "You are rewarded with a video";
                break;
            case 8 :
                message = "You are rewarded with a the green smiley face in the homepage";
                break;
            case 10 :
                message = "You are rewarded with a video";
                break;
            case 12 :
                message = "You are rewarded with a the red smiley face in the homepage";
                break;
            case 14 :
                message = "You are rewarded with a video";
                break;
            default :
                message="";
        }

        // custom dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

        SpannableString title = new SpannableString("YOU GAINED A REWARD");

        title.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.purple))
                , 0, title.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
        dialog.setTitle(title);

        text.setText(message);

        Button dialogButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_OK);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }

    }
```

Stack Trace:

```
06-14 21:57:39.420 15488-15488/com.mima.chilltime E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mima.chilltime, PID: 15488
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mima.chilltime/com.mima.chilltime.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2989)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:111)
        at com.mima.chilltime.SharedPreferencesManager.<init>(SharedPreferencesManager.java:19)
        at com.mima.chilltime.SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance(SharedPreferencesManager.java:25)
        at com.mima.chilltime.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1690)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1094)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2979)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: Youre right, I should break them up and keep it small.

Comment: Edited question to make it more readable and hopefully to the point

Comment: Could you post a stacktrace?

Comment: I don't think the reason your app is crashing is because the pref manager is stored globally. It's hard to know for sure what makes it crash without the error message. On a side note, I believe you should try to figure this out by yourself for some time before posting your problem here (this is your 4th question today), try searching on Google.

Comment: try to use `SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());  instead of using this`

Comment: @NjeruCyrus That worked. Thank you. Place it as an answer and I will mark it

Comment: you are welcome I have posted it @mmkp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

instead of using `this`

Answer (score 0):

In the `SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance(this);` .... `this` refers to the particular activity (i.e. **not** global) (i.e. its lifecycle directly related to the **current** context).

On the other hand, if you clearly need a reference to the **global** state of your application, then you can use `ApplicationContext`.

From Android [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper#getApplicationContext%28%29) (*my emphasis*) :

> `public Context getApplicationContext()`
>
> Return the context of the single, **global** Application object of the
>   current process. This generally should only be used if you need a
>   Context whose lifecycle is **separate** from the current context, that is
>   **tied to the lifetime of the process rather than the current component**.

So change to:

```
SharedPreferencesManager prefManager = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```